# php ajax not returning expected result, possible json decode issue

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Paste the following code into PHP.

```
        $json = '[{"id":1,"quantity":1},{"id":2,"quantity":2},{"id":3,"quantity":3}]';
        $json2 = json_decode($json);

        foreach($json2 as $item){
            $item->total = 9;
        }

        foreach($json2 as $item){
            print_r($item);
             echo "<br>";
        }

        echo json_encode($json2);
```

The above code will display the following result. I will call this the "expected result"

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [quantity] => 2 [total] => 9 ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [quantity] => 2 [total] => 9 ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [quantity] => 2 [total] => 9 ) 
[{"id":1,"quantity":2,"total":9},{"id":1,"quantity":2,"total":9},{"id":1,"quantity":2,"total":9}]
```

Now, Following the same logic. Paste java script below

```
function test(){
    var json = [{"id":1,"quantity":1},{"id":2,"quantity":2},{"id":3,"quantity":3}]; 
    $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"Product/ajax_test",
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                    'json':json,
                }, 
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }//end success function
        });//end of ajax  
}
```

And paste the php below, I am using codeigniter frame work if this helps

```
  public function ajax_test(){
    $json = $this->input->post('json');
    $json2 = json_decode($json);
    foreach($json2 as $item){
        $item->total = 2;
    }
    echo json_encode($json2);
   }
```

I expect the above 2 piece of code to show something similar in the console as my "expected result", but nothing shows in the console. And if I change the above code to the following

```
public function ajax_test(){
        $json = $this->input->post('json');

        foreach($json as $item){
            $item["total"] = 2;
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

The above code will show result in console. the "total" property is not in the final result as if it simply gave back the original `$json` variable. And it is also weird I need to use `$item["total"]` instead of `$item->total`.

Question 1, What did I do wrong on the above?
Question 2, Since PHP is stateless, is there a way for me to trouble shoot ajax, by echoing out the php page in the console without json encoding it?, if this make sense.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` can decode a JSON object as either an object or an array.

```
$json = '[{"id":1,"quantity":1},{"id":2,"quantity":2},{"id":3,"quantity":3}]';
$json_with_objects = json_decode($json);
$json_with_arrays = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json_with_objects[0]->quantity;
echo $json_with_arrays[0]["quantity"];

var_dump($json_with_objects);
var_dump($json_with_arrays);
```

Presumably, though we can't know since you don't provide it, your code `$this->input->post()` is decoding with associative arrays instead of objects.